# except ValueError not triggering

Tags: python

I'm making a call to an external API (which is private, so I can't share it). For some reason, sometimes the API gives me an HTTPError, and sometimes it returns something which is not compliant with the rest of my code, which raises a `ValueError`.

```
for row in dataset.iter_rows():
    saved = True
    while saved:
        url = "http://api.website.com/rest/v3/search?id={0}&profile=large&format=json".format(row["id_to_search"]) 
        try:
            r = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
            result = json.loads(r)
            saved=False
            print result
        except urllib2.HTTPError: 
            print "too fast, waiting before retry"
            time.sleep(3)
        except ValueError:
            print "################ ValueError ################"
            time.sleep(5)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

However, if I run my code again, this `ValueError` isn't raised again for the same row : it seems to appear randomly. That's why I tried to catch it, wait, and then try again (see code above), but... :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-3ae7644de1fc> in <module>()
     16         try:
     17             r = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
---> 18             result = json.loads(r)
     19             saved=False
     20             print result

/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.pyc in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    336             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    337             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 338         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    339     if cls is None:
    340         cls = JSONDecoder

/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.pyc in decode(self, s, _w)
    363 
    364         """
--> 365         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    366         end = _w(s, end).end()
    367         if end != len(s):

/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.pyc in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    381             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    382         except StopIteration:
--> 383             raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
    384         return obj, end

ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

...it isn't caught. Any idea why ?

Comment: Is name `ValueError` assigned in current scope? If you have `ValueError = ...` in your scope, that name does not longer refers to built-in exception.

Comment: I don't know (not good at Python), how can I check that ?

Comment: Either you have `ValueError = ...` or `from x import *`, where `x` module contains object named `ValueError`.

Comment: Did you do something like `except urllib2.HTTPError, ValueError:` somewhere? If so, that doesn't do what you think it does. It catches a `urllib2.HTTPError` and assigns it to `ValueError`. You need to parenthesize the exception types you want to catch, if you want to catch multiple types in a single `except` clause.

Comment: @user2357112 right, if it's Python 2.x, your sample is another convoluted assignment.

Comment: What's the rest of your code?

Comment: Yes, it's Python 2. I don't have `ValueError = ...` nor `except urllib2.HTTPError, ValueError:` anywhere. It might be possible that one of the modules I'm using contains an object named `ValueError`... Do I have to go read the module's code to go around the problem ?

Comment: @fmalaussena only when you're using wildcard imports. That's why wildcard imports are discouraged, they pollute local namespace with objects you don't need.

Comment: Ok, good to know, thanks. I have no wildcard import. Update : I restarted the kernel, and it works now. I have no idea why, though, maybe it was because of someone else's code (!?)... Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @fmalaussena note that you can easily create [MCVE] - you just need to replace `urllib2.urlopen().read()` result with fake data, that raises `ValueError` when passed to `json.loads`. Then simply include minimal code that triggers ValueError not being caught.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had assigned other value to name `ValueError`.

MCVE:

```
import json
ValueError = None
try:
    json.loads("")
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Exception is not caught:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```